# How to limit what can be accessed from a DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, scope

I have a DLL with code that look like :

```
public class MyInterface
{
    private Class1 class1;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        class1.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //Do something...
    }
}
```

Other developers will be using this DLLs that I wrote. They are only suppose to use `MyInterface` and should not know about `Class1`. Using `Class1` directly could produce unexpected behaviors and introduce bugs.

Is there a way to only show a subset of what is inside the DLLs to developers using it?

Comment: You could make `Class1` internal, and warn the others that if they access it directly through reflection then all bets are off, and the bugs will be theirs to fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what the access modifiers are for. Make your class `internal`:

```
internal class Class1
{
}
```

It will be visible only inside the assembly. Check MSDN to read more on access modifiers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Comment: I guess I will have to put my unit test in the same project then. Right? Or use reflection...

Comment: Actually not, it is possible to have `internal` visible from some other assembly by using `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`. It's designed exactly for automated testing. Have a read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx